# How to configure Geonetwork to be accessed from remote machines?

Tags: geonetwork

I just installed [Geonetwork](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/) and have been playing around with it on our server (localhost:8080), now I want to access this from other machines on the network but when I type in the address I get a page not found error.

I found this [link through googling](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/I-can-t-access-Geonetwork-from-remote-machine-td4756419.html) and altered the jetty.xml file (I couldn't find a mapServices.xml file). As a result I can now get to the page but none of the mapping components work (they all still refer to geoserver on localhost). Is there a location where I can make this change once, instead of going through heaps of file and individual changes?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Opted for a different route. I already had tomcat on this machine so downloaded the war file and installed geonetwork this way. Now working on interfacing it with Postgres.

Comment: Just for other peoples reference I found this article helpful http://geonetwork-opensource.org/_static/foss4g2010/FOSS4G_Mastering_Advanced_GeoNetwork.pdf

Comment: You can also answer your own questions so people can upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the link you found through googling is a bit misleading. I was having this same problem after i installed it. What i did was to replace the "localhost" withing the jetty.xml file with "0.0.0.0". This host parameter does not mean what IP to allow through, it means it will listen on that particular interface IP. So it's not "your IP" really, it's the IP of the interface on your server that will be responding to the request. "0.0.0.0" means respond on all interfaces. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond to this. Second time around with GeoNetwork and its traveling much better, the above solution helped out alot. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, i added a comment to the thread you found googleing on Feb 23rd as well so people can understand this better if they find that link.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a URL assign to it, then you need to find out the IP address of the Geonetwork machine and enter http://geonetwork_ip_address:8080 on the remote machine.

Comment: Simple and brilliant :->